# Dynamic subtraction game with function

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Let's start with rules of the game:

There is one pile of n chips. The first player to move may remove as many chips as
desired, at least one chip but not the whole pile. Thereafter, the players alternate moving,
each player not being allowed to remove more chips than $f(x)$ where $x$ is the number of chips that opponent took on the previous move.

$f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} \text{ non-decreasing and }f(x)\ge x$.

1) For which $k$ player II has winning move, if $f(x)=x+2$?

2) Which player has winning move if $f(x)=x^2$?

I know that I have to find general form of the sequence $\{H_n\}\subset\mathbb{N}$ such that $H_0=1$ and $H_{k+1}=H_k+\min_{i\le k}\{H_i: f(H_i)\ge H_k\}$ but i dont see any property :(

Problem 2.

On the table lies a pile of $n$  chips. The first player can take any number of chips,
at least one, but not the whole stack. Then players make turns in turns, at
what each player must take at least one piece and at most:
- as many chips as the player in the previous move, if he took an even number of chips,
- one chips more than the player in the previous move, if he took the odd number
of chips.

The player who makes the last move wins. Indicate the winning move (if any) for
the player starting the game, if n = 105. For which values ​​n can the other player
win?

what is the solving algorithm when we have two conditions?

Comment: This is a generalized version of Nim. You have to do backwards induction, starting from all states at which the game ends.  What's missing from your description is that the player who takes the last chip loses, right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is fairly straightforward. Calculate the first few losing positions:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
n&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
H_n&1&2&3&4&6&10&20&40&80
\end{array}$$

At this point it’s pretty easy to see what’s going on: if $H_n>H_{n-1}+2$, then $H_{n+1}=2H_n$. The winning positions for Player II are the positions $H_n$, and they can be described by listing $H_0$ through $H_4$ individually and then giving a general formula for $H_n$ with $n\ge 5$.

I don’t at the moment see a general form for the $H_n$ in the second problem, though it is at least clear that Player I wins if the initial position is odd and greater than $1$.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot that in 2) $k=62$ so player II has winning move

Comment: @Piszczu: Player II has winning moves for $k=1,2,4,6,10,14,18,24,30,36,42,52,62,72,82,92,102,146,\ldots$, i.e., for all of the $H_n$ defined by the recurrence in your question; I just don’t see any nice closed description of these numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I add problem 2 with 2 conditions. What is the solving algorithm in this situation?

Comment: have you any idea how solv Problem 2?

Comment: @Piszczu: I’m afraid that I don’t; that sequence of losing initial positions seems to be pretty intractable. The non-linear function $f$ really makes things difficult.